# port forwarding not navigating to correct internal IP

Tags: networking, router, apache-http-server, ip, port-forwarding

I have just set up the Netgear C6300 Cable Modem Router and re set up all my internal IP's so my main PC will always be 192.168.0.2 and my server (ubuntu server) will always be 192.168.0.10

I have forwarded ports 80 (HTTP), 3306 (SQL), and 22 (SSH) directed at internal IP 192.168.0.10 (ubuntu server) yet canyouseeme is unable to see any of the ports and I am unable to navigate to my external IP address, but I can navigate to 192.168.0.10 and see the default apache page.

So for testing purposes I installed xampp and ran apache and mysql on my main machine (192.168.0.2) and I forgot to change the port forwarding to point to this internal IP.  canyouseeme still saw it though... and browsing to my external IP opened the default xampp page... even though the port forwarding is pointing to 192.168.0.10 and xampp is running on 192.168.0.2

How can I get my port forwarding to navigate my external IP address to my server? (192.168.0.10)  I believe everything is set correctly...

[Here is a screenshot of my router settings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KC5u1.png)
[Here is my server ifconfig.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Easrt.png)

But for some reason it doesn't want to forward to the Internal IP and stays on 192.168.0.2

Comment: I wonder if you have 192.168.0.2 set as your DMZ and maybe that overrides individual port mappings on your router.

Comment: I guess a lot of people have issues with this modem/router but I did find a solution that worked for me, confirming a few things and I will post my answer =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After scouring the net using the correct search terms, I found thread after thread of people having issues with this router/modem.

There were different ways people managed to get port forwarding to work correctly although most did not.

The solution that worked for me was to open the advanced tab navigate to setup > WAN setup and check Respond to Ping on Internet Port

Now port forwarding seems to be working fully and my site now loads on port 80 =)  http://its.dirtrif.com/

Comment: "check Respond to Ping on Internet Port" - weird. Seriously broken router firmware.

Comment: ikr lol, but it solved my issue.  maybe it will help others =)